# How to extract desired row from Mysql database using PHP script

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created one HTML form which takes input from user ,Now I need to search user inputed name in Mysql database and print details related to that user inputed name which is stored in Mysql database.
Below script is creating HTML form to take user input, Saved as "ProcessTracking.html".

```
<form action="details.php" method="get"/>
<h3 align="center"><FONT color=#CCFF66>ENTER SO NUMBER</h3>
<p align="center"> 

<input type="text" id="SO_Number" name="SO_Number"/>

</p>
<div style="text-align:center"> 
<button     type="submit" value="SEARCH">
   <img alt="ok" src=
   "http://www.blueprintcss.org/blueprint/plugins/buttons/icons/tick.png"/> 
   SEARCH
  </button>
 </form>
```

Below PHP script named as "details.php"

```
   <?php
$userinput = $_GET['SO_Number'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ProcessTrackingSystem";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
exit();
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM   ProcessTrackingSystem.ProcessDetails WHERE SO_Number = '$userinput'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
#printf ("SO_Number: %s \n",$row["SO_Number"])
#print_r($row);

printf ("SO_Number:");
printf($row["SO_Number"]);
printf ('--||--');
printf ("Name:");
printf($row["Name"]);
printf ('--||--');

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: check syntax `print_r($row)`;

Comment: Blank page means error. Such errors can be found in the log files.

Comment: than how to print the retrieved data in web page??

Comment: where i can get log files??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log

Comment: And use error_reporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstlly you are not using the $_GET['SO_Number'] parameter in a WHERE of SQL statement. Secondlly you are using both mysql and mysqli which are totaly diffrent and don't work together. For usage see [mysqli_fetch_row()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_row.asp) and [mysqli_query()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp). Also use `print_r($row);`.

Here is the corrected code:

```
<?php
$userinput = $_GET['SO_Number'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ProcessTrackingSystem";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ProcessTrackingSystem.ProcessDetails WHERE SO_Number = '$userinput'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

print_r($row);

$conn->close();
?>
```

**EDIT:** Added code example.

Comment: ya i changed sir, now its working , but its showing only results, if i want names of the column than how can i change the script?

Comment: then you print the name like so: printf ("SO_Number: %s (Name: %s)\n",$row["SO_Number"],$row["Name"]);

Comment: sir print_r doesn't work for me so i changed to printf,

Comment: Oh yeah I accidently didn't change your previous answer, I just copied it and changed the string.

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed `mysql` and `mysqli` api together. Try using either one.

*Note: `mysql` api is deprectaed as of php 5.5.0*

Comment: This is not the answer , please try to add this in comment

Comment: You have initialized the connection using `mysqli` and querying the database with `mysql`. They are separate apis.
If you need to find a certain row containing the user input you need to add a `WHERE` clause.

Don't have the comment privilege yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

**1st Error**

As [saty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4662759/saty) says it is because of the syntax error you have in this line

```
print_r"$row";
```

which should be as `print_r($row)`

**2nd Error**

You're mixing `mysql` & `mysqli`

I am not sure about the table that you have.

**Recommendation :**

I would recommend you to turn on the **error_reporting** if not those errors will be in your `errors_log` file

Also for **debugging your sql**, you can first construct your sql query, run in the phpmyadmin or related tools for your query, then fire the query and make this done.

**Note :**

If you are using these code in online then the `error_log` will be in the directory where you execute this page. (But it may change according to your hosting)

If you are running in local machine the error log may locate according to the server you use...

You can find by printing the php's configuration by `phpinfo` and find for
`error_log`

Answer (score 0):

May this thing will fix your issue

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "ProcessTrackingSystem";
    $so = $_POST['SO_Number'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ProcessDetails WHERE SO_Number=$so");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

print_r($row[SO_Number]);
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: same Blank page i am getting sir.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you use get method in form just replace it with method="POST" or in PHP replace it $so = $_GET['SO_Number'];

Comment: I made some changes now try it.

Comment: I chenge the whole code add tested it, it will give you the output of SO_Number. IF it working than you can get all the details from that row.